# how to test property value after calling void method in c# unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I'm new to Unit Testing. I tried to test property value after calling void method but test fail. For this task I created mock object and setup property value and test successfully while dealing with property. When I call "Calling()" Method its assigning the string value to that property now I want to test that assigned value in unit testing after calling void method.

Thanks in advance any help to save my time today.

```
public class ClassTest
{
        [Fact]
        public void Demo_Calling_Test()
        {
            var mock=new Mock<IDemo>();
            mock.SetupProperty(x => x.Name, "test");
            var result=mock.Object.Name;
            Assert.Equal("test", result);
            mock.Setup(x => x.Calling());
            Assert.Equal("Calling", result);
        }
}

public interface IDemo
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        void Calling(); 
    }

public class Demo : IDemo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public void Calling()
        {
            Name = "Calling";
            //Calling
        }
    }
```

When I run my test case its working fine up to this line i.e Assert.Equal("test",result);, After that i'm getting error, that error message which I copy and paste here.
Message: 
Assert.Equal() Failure
↓ (pos 0)
Expected: Calling
Actual:   test
↑ (pos 0)

Comment: With the code you've posted, I'm not sure why Mock is being used _at all_. Your unit test is for the specific implementation of the `Demo` class's Calling method, so the interface also doesn't matter here.

Answer (score -1):

To test the value assigned to the `Name` property after calling the `Calling()` method, you need to invoke the `Calling()` method on the mock object and then verify the value of the `Name` property

```
[Fact]
public void Demo_Calling_Test()
{
    // Arrange
    var mock = new Mock<IDemo>();
    mock.SetupProperty(x => x.Name, "test");

    // Act
    mock.Object.Calling(); // call the method to set the value of the Name property

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal("Calling", mock.Object.Name);
}
```

Comment: But why use Mock at all? The test is the _specific_ implementation of the Calling method from the `Demo` class.

Comment: @mw509 : your code test failed, why because property value is test even after call "mock.Object.Calling()" this method.

Comment: @gunr2171: I already I tried without mock test success, but I got the task to do with mock so i'm tring to do with mock, can you help me if is their any possible way...

Comment: then it's possible that there might be some issue with your implementation. the Calling() method could actually not be setting the value of the Name property. add some debugging to see. or write a test to see if it returns anything